# how to derive local clocks from global clocks in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog

...Basically trying to mimic what would happen in a real chip, where the hardware is agnostic of the clock rate and we have a clock generator that controls the clock rate of various components, e.g. for a 2GHz clock source, you can propagate the signal to a processor every 2 cycles, for a 1 GHz processor operation frequency, every 4 cycles to the NoC for a 500 MHz operating frequency

Comment: It seems that you are asking a very large question about clock design.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a lot of documentation on the web and many books. In your favorite search engine, search for `verilog clock divider`. There is no sufficient differences between Verilog and System Verilog, expectantly for this kind of design.

If you want to make it look more like System Verilog, use `always_ff @...` instead of `always @...` and `always_comb begin` instead of `always begin` or `assign`. There is not real difference with a good coding style. Using the SV keywords just adds constraints that improves the changes that your functioning RTL is synthesizable.